# How to find missing file in my github submodule

Tags: github, git-submodules

I am new to git, so I used git to put my ionic project folder into local repository then push it, it did not appear as the normal repository I saw.

It then becomes submodule, so I cloned the repository, then the folder became empty, then I could not find my file but a empty folder.

> Can someone tell me how to find my missing file and why I tried to push a simple folder then it becomes submodule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> put my ionic project folder into local repository then push it, it didn't appear as the normal repository I saw , It becomes submodule

That is because your ionic project folder *already* included its own `.git/` subfolder.

Once copied into your local repo (which also has its own `.git/` subfolder), the ionic project folder is considered as a nested repository, and only a **[gitlink](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fast-import#Documentation/git-fast-import.txt-Inlinedataformat)** (reference to the root tree SHA1 of ionic/) is recorded and pushed by your local repository.
Hence the "submodule-like" empty folder on the remote side.

If you don't care about the history of that project, you could simply copy its files into your local repo, add, commit and push.

Comment: so that's mean my file is missing and can't be found forever?  so If I found the .git/ subfolder and delete it then I can update the whole folder normally instead of turning into a submodule? or I just clone all the file instead of folder into my repo as  you said ?

Comment: " so If I found the .git/ subfolder and delete it then I can update the whole folder normally instead of turning into a submodule?" exactly. And you can then move the files one folder up, if you don't won't them in a subfolder.